Is there a function to tell Click() in javascript, to stop at a specified number of clicks?
I am trying to write a bookmark-let, which I will run on a website.
javascript:(function() {window.setInterval(function () { 
            document.getElementsByClassName("some class")[0].click();}, 2000);}());

This code runs a function and it keeps clicking on the "some class" button. Every new click brings up more data, and then the button disappears to reappear after few seconds, and then the code keeps running non stop.
I want the code to stop at 100 clicks, please how can i go about it.
i have tried using for loop and clearInterval, it doesn't work on it.
I have searched on here for similar questions for two days. I didn't find, i am sorry if i am repeating a question, if the question is answered already, kindly direct me there.
I will greatly appreciate a quick response.
EDIT: @robby-cornelissen I cannot seem to find the solution, I am not a javascript programmer, I am a data analyst. I only use scripts sometimes to extract and analyse data.
this is a bookmarklet, and it's to be run on a console. this is the only way i know how to write a bookmarklet, please help me.

Don't see much sense in introducing a for loop anywhere, you should rather increment a counter variable. And to be able to clear the interval, you need to store the reference to it somewhere first of all.

I am not an expert in programming, I am a data guy, so I would appreciate you writing out the code, then i can try it out. i am using this to extract data. trying to automate everything, instead of clicking, so i can be doing something else, while this is going on.

Something like javascript: (function() {let c=0, i=window.setInterval(function() { /*click stuff here*/ if (++c>99) { clearInterval(i); }}, 2000);}());
